# Could not load file or assembly 'BouncyCastle.Crypto, Version=1.8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#

I am trying to integrate the Walmart .NET SDK into a .NET 4.61 MVC 5 app. Using NuGet, I added a reference to BouncyCastle.Crypto 1.8.1.0.

The SDK uses .NET Standard 1.3 and it references BouncyCastle.Crypto 1.8.1.3:

https://github.com/walmartlabs/partnerapi_sdk_dotnet

1.8.1.3 is not available for .NET 4.61.

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'BouncyCastle.Crypto, Version=1.8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"BouncyCastle.Crypto, Version=1.8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"}

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = BouncyCastle.Crypto, Version=1.8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/example_user/Source/Workspaces/CCC/Test/example_app.Test.DataAccessUnitTest/bin/Debug
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : Walmart.Sdk.Base, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\example_user\Source\Workspaces\CCC\Test\example_app.Test.DataAccessUnitTest\bin\Debug\example_app.Test.DataAccessUnitTest.dll.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/example_user/Source/Workspaces/CCC/Test/example_app.Test.DataAccessUnitTest/bin/Debug/BouncyCastle.Crypto.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/example_user/Source/Workspaces/CCC/Test/example_app.Test.DataAccessUnitTest/bin/Debug/BouncyCastle.Crypto/BouncyCastle.Crypto.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/example_user/Source/Workspaces/CCC/Test/example_app.Test.DataAccessUnitTest/bin/Debug/BouncyCastle.Crypto.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/example_user/Source/Workspaces/CCC/Test/example_app.Test.DataAccessUnitTest/bin/Debug/BouncyCastle.Crypto/BouncyCastle.Crypto.EXE.
```

Comment: The dll is not in you bin folder (either debug or release).  To prove I'm correct take the BouncyCastle and put into the proper bin folder.  If this works then do following : Add Existing Item and then browse for the BouncyCastle executable.  The compiler will then copy the latest BouncyCastle to the bin folder whenever you build.

Comment: Hi, I see no bouncy castle EXE because I am using .NET 4.61. I am not using .NET Core. The .DLL exists in the debug folder of my software.

Answer (score 3):

My issue was a project building concurrently in the same solution which was referencing an older library through NuGet and occasionally it was overwriting the most recent one. Upgrading the NuGet package in this project fixed the issue.

Comment: This did help me. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it helped

Answer (score 2):

I had to use the .NET 46 solution. The Walmart.Sdk.Base assembly is built on .NET Standard 1.3. I needed to reference the one for .NET 4.6.

Answer (score 0):

This error says.. BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll file is not exist in the project bin folder. I placed to dll file into the bin folder from my old project. Thats work for me.